# FF and Chrome different views - can't find the reason (maybe FF bug?)

Tags: jquery, css

I wrote a jQuery script which checks the browser height and compares to the height of the content-panel. If the panel is bigger then the window-height, the script makes everything smaller.

It works good in Chrome and Safari. On Firefox it's not working at all. Can anyone tell me what is causing the problem in detail?

Link to the site:
http://design.maxxcoon.com/bestlife/webinar_chat/

Comment: 100% same on me, ok I found the difference and answered.

Comment: Not seeing any sort of scaling effect in Chrome (39.0), and FF (31.2) is giving me normal min/max width scaling and that's it. You can do the effect you're looking for in pure CSS via something like `font-size:calc(8pt + 1vh);` which locks the minimum font size at 8pt, but adds 1% of the window height to it, by the way.

Comment: You have to reload to see the scaling effect.

Comment: @Shaggy It only scales on page load? That's.... kinda dumb tbh. Potentially "helpful" on a mobile browser with its fixed size, but on a desktop browser, people resize the window all the time (fullscreen to windowed alone). Feels like wasted effort if it's only onload

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(window).bind('resize', reSize($('#blocker')));
        $(window).trigger('resize');
        var windowSize = $(window).height();
        var containerHeight = $('.newcontainer').height() + 50;
        var containerWidth = $('.newcontainer').width();
        var pixelToMuch = 0;
        var divFactor = 0;
        var newWidth = 0;
        if (containerHeight > windowSize) {
            pixelToMuch = containerHeight - windowSize;
            divFactor = pixelToMuch * 1.67;
            newWidth = containerWidth - divFactor;
            $('.newcontainer').css('width', newWidth + 'px');
        }
    }, 100);
    setTimout(function () {
        $('#chatfenster').css('height', $('.newcontainer').height() - 260 + 'px');
        $('#userlist').css('height', $('.newcontainer').height() - 350 + 'px');
    }, 150);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't fixed my problem :(
It's still not working in FF: http://design.maxxcoon.com/bestlife/webinar_chat/